# Issue with signature validation with SHA1withRSA algorithm

Tags: android, rsa, public-key-encryption

I want to verify my signature using public key. I have issue with parsing my public key value into `PublicKey` object in order to use it for signature validation.

Here is my code:

```
private fun verifySignature(rawData: String, encryptedData: String){
    val signature: ByteArray = encryptedData.toByteArray()
    try {
       val key: PublicKey = loadPublicKey()
       val s = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA")
               .apply {
                    initVerify(key)
                    update(rawData.toByteArray())
               }
       val valid: Boolean = s.verify(signature)
     }catch (e: Exception){
        Log.i("Utils", "verifySignatureException: $e")
     }
}

private fun loadPublicKey(): PublicKey {
    val data: ByteArray = decode(BuildConfig.signature_key.toByteArray(), DEFAULT)
    val spec = X509EncodedKeySpec(data)
    val fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
    return fact.generatePublic(spec)
}
```

Exception:

```
verifySignatureException: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$ParsingException: Error parsing public key
```

PublicKey raw: `ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEA3p7ZGKq8OTEZUzsPHSal5wPaNbQ8WvXjA2+AjuNx9mt9hMLEMfmWeObESqg/jPb3ezfwDSKjRklX+l8Lwh1++hJMf+M0CabIwkDNu0GpXt+bPYEON3/2A8OaxReIMnETO9FEbmbWMTn3AegUu4Y4BLso5FfnApi+2nvfVHvmfyYUC9EVNRcxce6QOlh3ZW6GOYvr6rL/QYmcB+WJgbsc2d/kPmV96/F7ErEP6CtNA0Ai1bP+jCkSxOPdxvDcfAUqX4O7shAESQdf8VTR3e+8Uh5nhR/IP6xn4zPEsEoH/O4F8PmhAPXdrJ8QBdcNw5PUDVoCL9+EZ/sQwYkA2/rfqQ==`

**UPDATE #1:**
I've used this algorithm to format my `SSH` public key to `X.509/SPKI` but verification is returning false. And I'm sure that both sides have same initial data (backend who is generating signature and app).

I havent found a lot of info how to convert that SSH key to right format but here is code I'm using

```
public class CertificateUtils {
    private static final int VALUE_LENGTH = 4;
    private static final byte[] INITIAL_PREFIX = new byte[]{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0x73, 0x73, 0x68, 0x2d, 0x72, 0x73, 0x61};
    private static final Pattern SSH_RSA_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("ssh-rsa[\\s]+([A-Za-z0-9/+]+=*)+.*");

// SSH-RSA key format
//
//        00 00 00 07             The length in bytes of the next field
//        73 73 68 2d 72 73 61    The key type (ASCII encoding of "ssh-rsa")
//        00 00 00 03             The length in bytes of the public exponent
//        01 00 01                The public exponent (usually 65537, as here)
//        00 00 01 01             The length in bytes of the modulus (here, 257)
//        00 c3 a3...             The modulus

    public static RSAPublicKey parseSSHPublicKey(String key) throws InvalidKeyException {
        Matcher matcher = SSH_RSA_PATTERN.matcher(key.trim());
        if (!matcher.matches()) {
            throw new InvalidKeyException("Key format is invalid for SSH RSA.");
        }
        String keyStr = matcher.group(1);

        ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(decode(keyStr));

        byte[] prefix = new byte[INITIAL_PREFIX.length];

        try {
            if (INITIAL_PREFIX.length != is.read(prefix) || !Arrays.equals(INITIAL_PREFIX, prefix)) {
                throw new InvalidKeyException("Initial [ssh-rsa] key prefix missed.");
            }

            BigInteger exponent = getValue(is);
            BigInteger modulus = getValue(is);

            return (RSAPublicKey) KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent));
        } catch (IOException | InvalidKeySpecException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new InvalidKeyException("Failed to read SSH RSA certificate from string", e);
        }
    }

    private static BigInteger getValue(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        byte[] lenBuff = new byte[VALUE_LENGTH];
        if (VALUE_LENGTH != is.read(lenBuff)) {
            throw new InvalidParameterException("Unable to read value length.");
        }

        int len = ByteBuffer.wrap(lenBuff).getInt();
        byte[] valueArray = new byte[len];
        if (len != is.read(valueArray)) {
            throw new InvalidParameterException("Unable to read value.");
        }

        return new BigInteger(valueArray);
    }
}
```

Here is edited `loadPublicKey` function:

```
private fun loadPublicKey(): PublicKey {
        val keyRaw = BuildConfig.signature_key
        val key = CertificateUtils.parseSSHPublicKey(keyRaw)
        return key
}
```

**UPDATE #2:**

Also I tried to convert this ssh-rsa key into `X.509/SPKI` format as @Topaco suggested.

This was my public key after I removed header and footer + line breaks:

```
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA61BjmfXGEvWmegnBGSuS+rU9soUg2FnODva32D1AqhwdziwHINFaD1MVlcrYG6XRKfkcxnaXGfFDWHLEvNBSEVCgJjtHAGZIm5GL/KA86KDp/CwDFMSwluowcXwDwoyinmeOY9eKyh6aY72xJh7noLBBq1N0bWi1e2i+83txOCg4yV2oVXhBo8pYEJ8LT3el6Smxol3C1oFMVdwPgc0vTl25XucMcG/ALE/KNY6pqC2AQ6R2ERlVgPiUWOPatVkt7+Bs3h5Ramxh7XjBOXeulmCpGSynXNcpZ/06+vofGi/2MlpQZNhHAo8eayMp6FcvNucIpUndo1X8dKMv3Y26ZQIDAQAB
```

And I used this function to convert it into Public Key entity:

```
private fun loadPublicKeyPKCS(): PublicKey {
        val data: ByteArray = decode(BuildConfig.signature_key.toByteArray(), DEFAULT)
        val spec = X509EncodedKeySpec(data)
        val fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
        return fact.generatePublic(spec)
    }
```

Still verify was `false`. I'm not sure where is the problem now.

Comment: The code expects a public key in X.509/SPKI format, your key seems to be in SSH format.

Comment: And how can I convert my public key in SSH format to this new one? Is there any easy solution for this?

Comment: E.g. with `ssh-keygen: ssh-keygen -f <pub-file> -e -m pkcs8` for the X.509/SPKI format, see also [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30074). This converts to a PEM encoded key. Remove header, footer and line breaks and Base64 decode the rest to get a DER encoded key that `X509EncodedKeySpec` can handle.